# What triggers the new fist bump animation?

Tags: splatoon-3

Sizzle Season introduced a new animation during victory scene, when Inklings/Octolings perform their emotes a "fist bump" animation may occur between two players.

[image]

According to [Splatoon 3's Twitter account](https://twitter.com/SplatoonNA/status/1663561419567276032):

> Did you know that when two players on the winning team perform exceptionally well, they'll do a fist bump after their victory emotes?

But what does this mean exactly? Is this tied to the kill/death ratio? Or is this related to medals obtained in that game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three requirements:

- two players in the team must get 3 gold medals (it is impossible for more than two people to get 3 medals because the game only awards 8)
- they must be adjacent to each other
- their victory emote must be in the same "height range".

[image: Pose and requirements chart]

Source: [LeanYoshi](https://twitter.com/LeanYoshi/status/1665453189187919874)